# MySQL Extremely Large Table Size

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Our org uses MySQL for their heklpdesk ticket system, there's a table in there that has 14k rows adn the table is 5.7GB! Here's the table structure.

[image: swticketposts]

Any ideas why this table could grow so large, and any thoughts how can I reduce it in size? I've ran repair, check and optimize operations and I'm on the verge of purging old records, but can't think whats making this table so large! Lots of Medium Texts?

Comment: 5 GB is small to medium by modern standards, not large :)

Comment: are you inserting the mail body as well in this table..if yes then this table size is growing up due the mail body text.

Comment: The `contents` column looks like a likely culprit.  Can you run a query to select `average(char_length(contents))` ?

Comment: +1 for the contents column. If the ticket system just dumps mail bodies into the database, those also contain any attachments. I set up an OTRS instance once which did that by default. It filled up the maximum allowed MySQL DB size of 100MB in a matter of days...

Comment: The average length for the contents is 425089.7 so I guess that's the culprit, multiplying that figure by 14,000 gives somewhere in the region of 5GB so not much, apart from archiving we can do then eh!

Comment: 5 GB is tiny. I have tables with over 1 billion rows and sitting at the 800GB range and they still respond effectively. The medium text is your problem. So are you just concerned about size? Or is the table slow? Kind of lost on what the actual question is.

Comment: Hi, I was just curious if I'd missed any other operations to reduce the size of the table effectively and if in fact something had got corrupted. I'll archive off some of the rows as I imagine a lot of the data is no longer current.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the **contents** field to another table

like

```
 ticketpostid |   contents  |
_____________________________
```

then fetch the contents based on ticketpostid only when required.

Comment: So then he will move 5gb of the data into another table? Doubt that is going to make much difference as you are just moving the data into another table.

Comment: Medium text (blob) columns are stored in MySQL as a pointer (9 to 12 bytes). The actual blobs are stored outside of the table data. As long as you're not referencing the blob column in a query, there should be no noticeable difference having the column in there.

Comment: @Ami you are 100% correct. If you do a SELECT * FROM Table it would read the blobs and cause problems. Splitting into two tables however will no improve performance if the query is SELECT ticketpostid FROM table for example. Still a bit of a mystery what the question is about.